# The trie in Flexgrid + Angular 5

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular5, wijmo, wijmo5

I'm using Wijmo 5.2x in an Angular 5 project and i would like to make the sorting in a table.
I have a method that retrieves rows of correspondences, and it allows to modify them.
the problem is when i click on this method (it's checkbox), it gets the correspondences but it changes the order, and also when i try to sort, the values of the columns change by themselves (which i don't want).

I mean the rows change their order and most columns folow the new order of the rows but two columns do not (one of them is the column of the check boxes).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you would like to prevent the sort operation while editing the content of the FlexGrid cell. 
If yes, the behaviour you are observing is by design. And it can be modified by assigning sorting items to CollectionView sourceCollection and set canSort to false to prevent sorting. 
Please refer to the fiddle sample that implements the same.

<    http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo5/xa356c78/>

~Manish